# Grid with col-auto and big table

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a side menu and some content right of it. I've made it into simple grid system, but if I have big table (a lot of columns), even though I set it with `.table-responsive`, it get shoved to the new row.

Left menu have `.col-auto`, so it would take only as little space as is needed (this could vary depending on language), rest have `.col` so it would take all the remaining sapce. Is there a way to have big scrollable table on same row as menu?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68bzpomx/)

Hope it makes sense,
Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please do not just point us to code linked to another website. Code on that site might change or disappear over time, leaving the question here without any context for future readers. Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76950834/edit) and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question